# NodeJS - how can I make my code beautiful / cleaner / better readable

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I have generated my app with `express --view=pug myapp` which created me a folder-tree with the files I need to start over.. I wrote some code which I would like to outsource from the main `app.js` in maybe a function-file or something like that, to keep the `app.js` cleaner.

where would I put my custom functions? how would I then require the function-file in nodeJS ?

Comment: Serach for good nodejs project structures. You can see one tutorial [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-node-js-project-structure-tutorial/). Also, keep in mind of the various [design patterns](https://medium.com/@kalin.chernev/reflecting-on-node-js-design-patterns-6cc6eaa584). All the decisions you make solely depends on the specific problem you are trying to solve, and thus there is no right/wrong answer.

Comment: Hi.. thank you very much.. the first link is interesting, because  of RULE #1 .. when I do `express --view=pug myapp` it creates me exact this structure, they say should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can arrange your files as you wish. Wherever you keep your functions, just add the functions you want to use in any other files to `module.exports` object in that file. Then in your app.js (or any other file where you want to use these functions), import the file using `require` and you should have access to all the exported properties and functions from the file you import.

For example:

I can put my functions in ./lib/core-lib.js:

```
function test(){
  // do something
}

module.exports = {
  test: test
};
```

And then in my app.js

```
const lib = require('./lib/core-lib');


lib.test();
```